# Can someone help me find concise and complete instructions for WDS?

Tags: deployment, wds, unattended

I've gotten it to work once for a smaller deployment.  Now I'm building a new image (Windows 7 Pro x86) to capture but I can't get it to work again because I think the instructions I use aren't really precise and clear (I'm using [this](http://blog.augustoalvarez.com.ar/2010/04/20/deploying-windows-7-using-windows-deployment-services-wds-step-by-step-part-i/)), while helpful, it confuses me on some parts (like the answer file and capturing the image properly.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using for WDS?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning.  WDS is on a Server 2008 machine and I'm deploying Windows 7 Pro x86

Comment: What is confusing you, or where are you getting stuck?

Comment: My main issue right now is setting up the unattended and oobe xml file for my new capture.  I'm not sure if it is associated with my captured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Technet base article with links to other articles for more advanced topics.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670(WS.10).aspx

That should give you all the info you need to get going.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [MDT 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791) to create your image?  It ties in nicely with WDS and comes with some excellent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this technet article pretty straight forward:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637993(v=WS.10).aspx